# Is it possible to make streams of non-POD types?

Tags: c++, iostream, streambuf

In C++, I need to make streams of objects which are of non-POD type using my own implementation of `std::basic_streambuf<Type>`. Is the standard library required to construct/destroy the objects when expected?

Comment: I'm not so sure. You don't usually see `std::basic_streambuf<std::string>`.

Comment: @DeadMG: oh sorry, I misunderstood the question then :) I deleted my comment to avoid confusion

Comment: Yes, is the only answer I can imagine for this one. Although it does rather depend on what you mean by 'expected'.

Comment: All I can see so far is 27.2.2:2 *In the classes of Clause 27, a template formal parameter with name charT represents a member of the set of types containing char, wchar_t, and any other implementation-defined character types that satisfy the
requirements for a character on which any of the iostream components can be instantiated.* Hmm, not very helpful...

Comment: I don't know how Meaningful it is, you may want to serialize, you need to specialize `std::char_traits` and `std::allocator` for your `T`. but there better ways to serialize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but you might need to implement some missing iostream, char_traits, members/friend functions. Some basic functionality like ostream::write might work out of the box.